# XSD with length value 0 isn't being honored

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd2code

I have a question with an XSD that I am working with.

I have the following block:

```
          <xs:element name="Artist">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:length value="0" />
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:element>
```

I would expect that the string would be limited to 0. However when I use an online sample generator, the string can be of any length.

Could anyone give me some insight as to what is really happening? Does 0 have a special action for xml generation?

Comment: I would say the sample generator you are using is in error.  Using Visual Studio and setting either length or maxLength to 0 has it generating an empty field.

Comment: Odd using XSD2Code it works along with www.xsd2xml.com the following block works:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="Artist">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:length value="0" />
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:element>
</xs:schema>

Comment: Is there a reason to believe that the online sample generator you are using is error-free and pays attention to all facets in the declarations of simple types?

Comment: I am not sure what is going on with the samplers I use. I do no that MOST seem to not care. I have made the change regardless. Interesting though.